# using find with rsync to copy files with word syntax to another location/directory

Tags: bash, shell, find, rsync

I want to create a script to copy files on incremental basis from directory A to directories AB, AC, AD, etc.

For example, I have files in the directory A like `world_test.txt`, `world1_test.txt` `world2_test.txt`. I want to copy files with all names of `world_test` to folder AB and so on.

I tried below script but failed

```
find /path/ -name "world_test" -type f | xargs -i rsync ... {} /var/AB \;
```

Can anyone correct the script or suggest another command?

Comment: Why not use `rsync` properly? `rsync -ua /path/to/world_test** /newpath`? (note, you can adjust the options as needed)

Comment: Hi David, the source folder has thousand of files with different name so i need to find the files first and then rsync to destination

Comment: The problem you run into in building a list and then calling `rsync` for each file, you will be invoking `rsync` thousands of different times rather than finding a wildcard allowing you to invoke `rsync` once for many files.

Answer (score 0):

Below command worked for me

```bash
find . -type f -name '*file-name*' -exec rsync -aR '{}' /folder-name \;
```